# How do I configure the Mac so that I can switch between two desktops/spaces from which the first one is always shown on an external screen?

Tags: desktop, spaces

For presentation I would like to show Firefox and VSCode on an external screen.
But sometimes I would like to do something on the Laptop withot showing it on the external screen, but leave that with Firefox and or VSCode.

So mirroring is not what I want. And extending the screen means that I do not see on the laptop what is on the external screen.

What I want to achieve is that I can present one desktop and from time to time switch on the laptop to another desktop. This should not alter that on the external screen is still the first main desktop shown.

Comment: Does [extending desktop](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlb5f905a1/mac) address the problem?

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to show Firefox and VSCode on an external display and then swap out Firefox and VSCode with a desktop from your laptop? Or did you somehow want to show the desktop as well as Firefox and VSCode at the same time?

Comment: No extending is not what I want, as I cannot work on what is seen on the external screen while presenting it to the audience.